# Does edb header indicate the number of pages in the edb database?

Tags: edb

How do I determine the number of pages in a Microsoft Extensible Storage Engine (e.g., Windows .edb) database?

I've looked at edb and ese documentation to see if the number of pages in an edb database is in the header, but I don't see this.

Does the edb header contain the number of pages in the database?   If not, how could that be determined?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure why you need it to be in the header, but there is an API called `JetGetDatabaseFileInfo` if you haven't attached the database:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/extensible-storage-engine/jetgetdatabasefileinfo-function

There is also `JetGetDatabaseInfo` if you have already attached it.
Are you interested in file size? Or the number of pages that the engine thinks it is (`JET_DbInfoSpaceOwned`)?